# Как организовать универсальный шаблон с возвратом значения функции?

Tags: c++

```
template<class F>
class SafeCall
{
    F *funcPtr;

public:
    SafeCall(F* func):funcPtr(func){}

    template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
    typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type
    Invoke(Func f, Args&&... args)
    {
        void* ret_addr_in_stack = _AddressOfReturnAddress();
        uintptr_t temp = *(uintptr_t*)ret_addr_in_stack;
        *(uintptr_t*)ret_addr_in_stack = 0;

        typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type && ret_val=f(args...);

        *(uintptr_t*)ret_addr_in_stack = temp;

        return ret_val;
    }


    template<class... Args>
    __forceinline decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        return InvokeShellCode(funcPtr,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Мне нужно, чтоб при вызове `Invoke` очищался адрес возврата из стека,по этому надо его восстановить после завершения проксирования функции : `*(uintptr_t*)ret_addr_in_stack = temp;`, но если тип функции void, тогда происходит ошибка:

```
 typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type && ret_val=f(args...);
 //невозможно преобразовать "void" в "int &&"
```

Непонятно откуда там вообще берется тип int, но и не понятно как сделать универсальную функцию, в которой после вызова проксируемой функци, мы бы могли совершить какие то действия, то есть не писать вот так: `return f(args...)`

```
(SafeCall<decltype(Beep)>(Beep))(500,500);//Все ок
(SafeCall<decltype(Sleep)>(Sleep))(500);//Все не ок
```

Comment: Делайте `if constexpr` вариант для функций, возвращающих void.

Comment: @user7860670 думал, но неужели нет более изящных вариантов это сделать?

Comment: Можно убрать действия работы с адресом ret_addr_in_stack в конструктор/деструктор временной переменной, и возвращать результат вложенной функции одним ретурном. Для функций возвращающих void есть исключение.

Comment: Поделитесь, для чего нужны манипуляции с адресом возврата?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat чтобы код нельзя было найти по стеку вызовов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

template<typename T>
class TempValueRestore
{
    T& ref;
    T old_value;
public:
    __forceinline TempValueRestore( T& ref, T new_value)
        : ref(ref)
    {
        old_value = ref;
        ref=new_value;
    }
    __forceinline ~TempValueRestore()
    {
        ref=old_value;
    }
};


template<class F>
class SafeCall
{
    F *funcPtr;

public:
    SafeCall(F* func):funcPtr(func){}

    template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
    decltype(auto)     Invoke(Func f, Args&&... args)
    {
        TempValueRestore< uintptr_t> restorer( *(uintptr_t*)_AddressOfReturnAddress(), 0 );
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }


    template<class... Args>
    __forceinline decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        return Invoke(funcPtr,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int foo(int,int) { return 0; }
void bar(int,int) { }

int main()
{
    (SafeCall<decltype(foo)>(foo))(500,500);//Все ок
    (SafeCall<decltype(bar)>(bar))(500,500);//Все не ок
}
```